# Why is there no current flowing through the relay coil in this Qucs 0.0.19 simple dc circuit?

Tags: relay, qucs

I just started looking at Qucs and am going through the components. I am puzzled by the results shown by the ammeters in the relay circuit below:

[image: Relay Circuit Qucs]

As you can see from the table, the circuit on the right is behaving as it would if the relay coil were energised, and showing 0.75 amps; but the circuit on the left is showing 0 for current, when it should obviously have a positive value there. I've tried swapping the coil terminals on the relay but the result is the same.

Comment: Mickey Mouse simulator

Comment: its actually a very capable simulator and in the field of microwave not many come close. The additional boltons are lacking but this was written while two people were doing their phd. Its unfortunately the only simulator for linux

Comment: @JonRB, ngspice is free and available for Linux.

Comment: @ThePhoton yer... I had to write netlists for SPICE when I was at uni, I don't really have time for that now :) rather boot up matlab tbf

Comment: I just checked a piece of software I used at uni (oregano). There is a simulator for it now, I might emerge it and try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In QUCS the relay (or relais as it is called internally) is a voltage controlled switch.

The primary side has infinite resistance when it is engaged or not engaged. When there is enough voltage across the primary it will close the secondary

https://github.com/Qucs/qucs/blob/develop/qucs/qucs/components/relais.cpp